# Find androidManifest flutter

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

This might be a very stupid question, but where do i find the AndroidManifest.xml?

I'm using IntelliJ and I'm trying to add a Google-map to my Flutter project.

I have read

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#package-name

and more...

As I understand it, I should find something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    ...
</manifest>
```

But I only find this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
```

I'm really sorry if the question is stupid, but it's a problem for me

Thanks

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can find like this.

myproject/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 15):

Look in:

*projectFolder*/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 7):

The above answer is correct, but you may also use the below shortcut key to quickly search AndroidManifest.xml file.

First:

- In Windows <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
- In Mac <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

Then:

- type AndroidManifest.xml in the search box & select the one with `android/app/src/main/` file path